# Design Pattern For Making An Assembler

Tags: c++, design-patterns, assembly, compiler-construction

I'm making an 8051 assembler.

Before everything is a tokenizer which reads next tokens, sets error flags, recognizes EOF, etc.
Then there is the main loop of the compiler, which reads next tokens and check for valid mnemonics:

```
mnemonic= NextToken();
if (mnemonic.Error)
{
    //throw some error
}
else if (mnemonic.Text == "ADD")
{
    ...
}
else if (mnemonic.Text == "ADDC")
{
    ...
}
```

And it continues to several cases. Worse than that is the code inside each case, which checks for valid parameters then converts it to compiled code. Right now it looks like this:

```
if (mnemonic.Text == "MOV")
{
    arg1 = NextToken();
    if (arg1.Error) { /* throw error */ break; }
    arg2 = NextToken();
    if (arg2.Error) { /* throw error */ break; }

    if (arg1.Text == "A")
    {
        if (arg2.Text == "B")
            output << 0x1234; //Example compiled code
        else if (arg2.Text == "@B")
            output << 0x5678; //Example compiled code
        else
            /* throw "Invalid parameters" */
    }
    else if (arg1.Text == "B")
    {
        if (arg2.Text == "A")
            output << 0x9ABC; //Example compiled code
        else if (arg2.Text == "@A")
            output << 0x0DEF; //Example compiled code
        else
            /* throw "Invalid parameters" */
    }
}
```

For each of the mnemonics I have to check for valid parameters then create the correct compiled code. Very similar codes for checking the valid parameters for each mnemonic repeat in each case.

So is there a design pattern for improving this code?
Or simply a simpler way to implement this?

Edit: I accepted plinth's answer, thanks to him. Still if you have ideas on this, i will be happy to learn them. Thanks all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've written a number of assemblers over the years doing hand parsing and frankly, you're probably better off using a grammar language and a parser generator.

Here's why - a typical assembly line will probably look something like this:

```
[label:] [instruction|directive][newline]
```

and an instruction will be:

```
plain-mnemonic|mnemonic-withargs
```

and a directive will be:

```
plain-directive|directive-withargs
```

etc.

With a decent parser generator like [Gold](http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/), you should be able to knock out a grammar for 8051 in a few hours.  The advantage to this over hand parsing is that you will be able to have complicated enough expressions in your assembly code like:

```
.define kMagicNumber 0xdeadbeef
CMPA #(2 * kMagicNumber + 1)
```

which can be a real bear to do by hand.

If you want to do it by hand, make a table of all your mnemonics which will also include the various allowable addressing modes that they support and for each addressing mode, the number of bytes that each variant will take and the opcode for it.  Something like this:

```
enum {
    Implied = 1, Direct = 2, Extended = 4, Indexed = 8 // etc
} AddressingMode; 

/* for a 4 char mnemonic, this struct will be 5 bytes.  A typical small processor
 * has on the order of 100 instructions, making this table come in at ~500 bytes when all
 * is said and done.
 * The time to binary search that will be, worst case 8 compares on the mnemonic.
 * I claim that I/O will take way more time than look up.
 * You will also need a table and/or a routine that given a mnemonic and addressing mode
 * will give you the actual opcode.
 */

struct InstructionInfo {
    char Mnemonic[4];
    char AddessingMode;
}

/* order them by mnemonic */
static InstructionInfo instrs[] = {
    { {'A', 'D', 'D', '\0'}, Direct|Extended|Indexed },
    { {'A', 'D', 'D', 'A'}, Direct|Extended|Indexed },
    { {'S', 'U', 'B', '\0'}, Direct|Extended|Indexed },
    { {'S', 'U', 'B', 'A'}, Direct|Extended|Indexed }
}; /* etc */

static int nInstrs = sizeof(instrs)/sizeof(InstrcutionInfo);

InstructionInfo *GetInstruction(char *mnemonic) {
   /* binary search for mnemonic */
}

int InstructionSize(AddressingMode mode)
{
    switch (mode) {
    case Inplied: return 1;
    / * etc */
    }
 }
```

Then you will have a list of every instruction which in turn contains a list of all the addressing modes.

So your parser becomes something like this:

```
char *line = ReadLine();
int nextStart = 0;
int labelLen;
char *label = GetLabel(line, &labelLen, nextStart, &nextStart); // may be empty
int mnemonicLen;
char *mnemonic = GetMnemonic(line, &mnemonicLen, nextStart, &nextStart); // may be empty
if (IsOpcode(mnemonic, mnemonicLen)) {
    AddressingModeInfo info = GetAddressingModeInfo(line, nextStart, &nextStart);
    if (IsValidInstruction(mnemonic, info)) {
        GenerateCode(mnemonic, info);
    }
    else throw new BadInstructionException(mnemonic, info);
}
else if (IsDirective()) { /* etc. */ }
```

Comment: My memory is about 200 KiB and I'm so happy you replaced the previous object-oriented code with this one! Now a follow-up (I know...) question: Was your previous way using `Instruction8051 { public string Mnemonic { get; set; } public List<InstructionInfo> Info { get; set; } }` the Command Pattern? And are there any reasons/situations I prefer Command Pattern to Look-up Tables?

Comment: Command Pattern?  No - both of them would've been geared around look up tables. The earlier C# code is just one that takes advantage of the language's support for generic collections and auto properties.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Most assemblers use a table of data which describes the instructions:  mnemonic, op code, operands forms etc.

I suggest looking at the source code for `as`.  <s>I'm having some trouble finding it though.</s>  Look [here](http://john.ccac.rwth-aachen.de:8000/as/download.html).  (Thanks to Hossein.)

Comment: @wallyk: I already thought of a look-up table which contains mnemonics, number of parameters for each mnemonic, their types, etc. But speed and memory are important for me here, as it's going to be run on a machine with little ram and slow processor. So i think it will be my last choice.

Comment: @Hossein: A lookup table would probably take no more memory than having multiple copies of the case code that you current have. As for performance, you probably wouldn't notice any difference. Your code is already using string comparisons and function calls, so it's not like you are optimizing a tight inner loop. Remember the 80/20 rule.

Comment: The table-driven approach is heavily tried and true for small memory, slow processor implementations.  Consider how much code it takes to set up each comparison in your approach.  In the table-driven approach, there is only one bit of code which does the comparison for, say, the mnemonic.  It's inside a loop which is no slower than a sequence of literal comparisons.  Try both:  I am confident you'll find the table is superior in most ways.

Comment: If speed and memory are your concerns you should definitely use a table.  One of the fastest assemblers for the Apple II came in at around 8K total and ran at several thousand lines per minute on a 1MHz machine.  What are your memory limitations?  I'd be surprised if you couldn't describe the entire instruction set and its addressing modes in under 1K.

Comment: "Smart data structures and dumb code works a lot better than the other way around." -- *The Cathedral and the Bazaar* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cathedral_and_the_Bazaar)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into the Visitor pattern.  It might not make your code that much simpler, but will reduce coupling and increase reusability. [SableCC](http://sablecc.org/) is a java framework to build compilers that uses it extensively.

Comment: Are you sure? I see Visitors mostly used in trees (like the T in AST). You don't exactly need/have a tree in an assembler, as opposed to a compiler for a larger language.

Comment: No but you could have a Mnemonic class that could define its output code through a visitor pattern.  You loop the Mnemonics, pass them the visitor, they return their own output.  I never designed an assembler, so it's just a guess heh.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the "Command Dispatcher" pattern?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

The general idea would be to create an object that handles each instruction (command), and create a look-up table that maps each instruction to the handler class. Each command class would have a common interface (Command.Execute( *args ) for example) which would definitely give you a cleaner / more flexible design than your current enormous switch statement.

Comment: I'd rather stay away from "too much" object-oriency because of performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

When I was playing with a Microcode emulator tool, I converted everything into descendants of an `Instruction` class.  From `Instruction` were category classes, such as `Arithmetic_Instruction` and `Branch_Instruction`.  I used a *factory* pattern to create the instances.

Your best bet may be to get a hold of the assembly language syntax specification.  Write a *lexer* to convert to tokens (**please, don't use if-elseif-else ladders).  Then based on semantics, issue the code.

Long time ago, assemblers were a minimum of two passes:  The first to resolve constants and form the skeletal code (including symbol tables).  The second pass was to generate more concrete or absolute values.

Have you read the Dragon Book lately?

Comment: Does the Dragon Book discuss assemblers too? I'm still trying to find a downloadable version of it or get a translated version but having succeeded.